# All items in webpage are moving upon resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made this webpage at http://www.caseums.com. I have used twitter bootstrap and fontaweome among other things , but I find that I am too much of a novice to determine the answer. I have searched the stack database but can't find a similar enough answer to answer my problem. If one was to re-size my page to be smaller, all of the items on page move in such a manner as to move out of the box they are in , namely the `<p>` elements.

I would love any information to help me answer this , I've been wrestling with it for awhile, thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to the `#Containment` div? Try using percentages for your widths. You currently have the width set to 325px, which will overflow if your window size is less than 325px.

Also take a look at [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries), if you need certain portions of your site to size differently dependant on the viewport size.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the `width` styles on `#Containment` and the `<div>` inside `#Containment`, to `max-width` instead, is that what you're after?